# Problem with NIntegrate inside NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

This is my first post on this site, please forgive me if I screw up to copy my code in a nice way..

I am trying to solve a set of 3 coupled differential equations with NDSolve, where one of the terms in the equations is obtained by NIntegrate. The set of equations looks as follows

```
NDSolve[{D[X[A], A] == (A^(7/2)/TRHb^5)*((Sqrt[3]*Mpl*RF[A,10^8,10^12])/Sqrt[Φ[A] + R[A]/A + (X[A]*Sqrt[mDM^2 + 9*κb^2*(A^(-3/2))^(1/2)])/TRHb]),

         D[Φ[A], A] == (-(A^(1/2)/TRHb^2))*((Sqrt[3]*Mpl*ΓbSM)/Sqrt[Φ[A] + R[A]/A + (X[A]*Sqrt[mDM^2 + 9*κb^2*(A^(-3/2))^(1/2)])/TRHb]), 

         D[R[A], A] == (ΓbSM*Φ[A] - (1/TRHb^4)*(2*Sqrt[mDM^2 + 9*κb^2*(A^(-3/2))^(1/2)]*RF[A,10^8,10^12]*A^3))*((Sqrt[3]*Mpl*A^(3/2))/(TRHb^2*Sqrt[Φ[A] + R[A]/A + (X[A]*Sqrt[mDM^2 + 9*κb^2*(A^(-3/2))^(1/2)])/TRHb])),

        X[10^(-10)] == 0,
        Φ[10^(-10)] == ΦI,
        R[10^(-10)] == 0},

        {X, Φ, R}, {A, 10^(-10), 10^4}]}
```

The function RF is the one which I need to solve with NIntegrate. The final goal is to solve this set of equations for X[A,mDM,λ]. In order to do so, I am trying to solve these equations on a "grid" of different mDM and λ values. Afterwards I fix A and use Interpolation in order to get a nice smooth solution in mDM and λ.
But I already struggle to get a solution just for a single combination of mDM and λ (mDM = 10^8, λ = 10^12).
I guess the main problem is in the function RF. It is defined as follows

```
RF[(A_)?NumericQ, (mDM_)?NumericQ, (mt_)?NumericQ, (αG_)?NumericQ, (λ_)?NumericQ]:=

 (4*Pi/(2048*Pi^6))*NIntegrate[

Norm[(Sqrt[1-(4*mDM^2)/s]*((mDM^2*s^3*(1-(4*mDM^2)/s))*(4 + 12*αG^2)^2)*κb*(A^(-3/2))^(1/4)*Sqrt[s]*BesselK[1, Sqrt[s]/(κb*(A^(-3/2))^(1/4))])/(λ^4*((s - mt^2)^2 + mt^2*((mt^3*((1/8)*Sqrt[1 - (4*89^2)/mt^2] + (3*αG^2)/16))/(Pi*λ^2) + (mt^3*Sqrt[1 - (4*mDM^2)/mt^2]*mDM^2*(1 - (4*mDM^2)/mt^2))/((Pi*λ^2)*8*mt^2))^2))],

                    {s, 4*mDM^2, Infinity}, Exclusions -> {mt^2, ma^2}]
```

As a function of A, RF[A] should look like FIG1. in [ https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.01947 ]. But I fail to reproduce this form in the rage mDM = [10^8 - 10^14]. As soon as NIntegrate hits the point s ~ mt^2, I get problems. I was trying to play around with the NIntegrate settings, but nothing really helped. I obtained the best solutions with "DoubleExponential" and "Trapezoidal", but in both cases I get Singaluarity errors. I guess I need to get first an error free solution in NIntegrate before I can use RF in NDSolve.
How can I get a nice integration for the entire range of mDM?

The parameters I used were

```
ma = 0;αS = 1; αV = 1/Log[10^5]; αH = 1; αG = 1/Log[10^5]; βG = 0; βV = 0; αχ = 1; αχV = 1; βχ = 0; βχ5 = 0; g = 100; V = 10^5; Mpl = 2*10^18; κinf = 10^17; κb = 9*10^8; ΦI = 4*10^43; ΓinfSM = 4*10^8; ΓbSM = 7/10^11; minf = 6*10^14; mt = 2*10^10; TRHinf = 2*10^13; TRHb = 7*10^4;
```

**Update**

Here are some plots of the function RF[A] for the parameters mDM = 10^8, 10^9, 10^10, 10^11, 10^12, 10^13. Inside NIntegrate I used

{s, 4 mDM^2, mt^2, Infinity}, Method -> "DoubleExponential", WorkingPrecision -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10.

```
Timing[Plot[RF[A, mDM, mt, αG, λ], {A, 10^(-10), 10^10}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I get the following error for the case of mDM=10^12

```
NIntegrate::ncvi: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 iterated refinements in s in the region {{4.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*10^20,\[Infinity]}}. NIntegrate obtained 9.2531746437536964660643301435717812896328729569142552371394`60.*^54 and 2.60922345176519777170004482614311324727140650854448718254727`60.*^53 for the integral and error estimates.
```

I guess before I use RF[A] as an input for NDSolve I need to get it as a smooth function for the entire parameter space.

Comment: I recommend stripping out the unimportant parts and simplifying the problem until you have the kernel of it. It's awkward picking through your code at the moment.

Comment: I just cleared up the code a little bit, I hope it is easier to understand now.

Comment: @ikarus What do you want to calculate here?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am trying to solve the 3 coupled Boltzmann equations, which describe the production of Dark Matter during Inflation. X is dark matter, Phi the inflaton and R is radiation. The function RF is the production rate of DM, i.e basically the decay of radiation to dark matter

Comment: @ikarus This is clear from the article. What is your problem? I checked the code on version 12 for Windows 10. Everything works.

Comment: @AlexTrounev In the end I want to obtain X[mDM,λ] for a fixed A. To do so, I want to solve the Boltzmann equations for a discrete set of values, i.e. mDM=[10^8 - 10^14] and λ=[10^12 - 10^18] and interpolate the result afterwards in the variable mDM and λ for a fixed A. 
My problem is that I cannot obtain an error-free result (which behaves like Fig1. in the upper reference) for RF in the entire parameter space. For instance if I plot RF[A] for the values mDM=10^10 and λ=10^12 I get convergence or singularity errors.

Comment: @ikarus The integral converges everywhere, but when the integrand becomes less than 10^-15, a message appears. It is necessary to put under the integral `AccuracyGoal -> 10`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for the help! I only get with "DoubleExponential" or "Trapezoidal" a similar slope in RF[A] in the range A = [10^(-10) - 10^0] as in Fig1. of the reference I gave. But with these Methods I get Singularity or convergence errors beyond mDM ~ mt. Setting AccurancyGoal -> 10 doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @ikarus What parameters did you set when calculating the curves in Fig. 1?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I integrated in the range {s, 4 mDM^2, mt^2, Infinity} and used Method -> "DoubleExponential", WorkingPrecision -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10. With these parameters I get almost the right solutions for mDM ~10^8 (only at the high end of A, RF[A] starts to look not right). But when I increase mDM I get problems. For mDM ~ 10^10 I don"t get a result at all. For 10^11 I get an errof-free result, but the RF[A] is discontinuous in this case, and for even higher values of mDM I get convergence problems

Comment: @ikarus Add in your topic code for calculating the curves in Fig. 1.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I added a few plots of RF[A] which show the problem

Comment: @ikarus In the article $m_{DM} = 10^4,10^9$, $\Lambda = 10^{16}$, $m_a=10^8$ and $m_t = 10^{10}, 10^{13}, 10^{15}$. Do you have other designations? Honestly, I don’t understand why there is to calculate  `RF` from $10^{-50}$ to $10^{50}$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, the parameters in the article are just benchmark values. I am trying do the analysis with parameters motivated by a UV-theory. In the end I want to produce plots like Fig.2/3.
What do you mean by RF from 10^{-50} to 10^{50}? I plot RF from 10^{-10} to 10^{10}, where A is just a parametrization for the temperature.

Comment: @ikarus In Fig.1 we see that RF changes from $10^{-50}$ to $10^{50}$. In a paper they are used " the exact solutions of the total production rate of the fermionic dark matter for a representative set of free parameters, as a function of the variable x = ms/T which may be regarded as a parametrization of time". It's ok! But for numerical calculations they used Cuba https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0404043.pdf

Comment: @AlexTrounev ah yes, that is true. But I was not quite sure how they where using Cuba, since it as a package for multidimensional integration and the integral is just one dimensional. So I was trying to solve the problem with NIntegrate and NDSolve.

Comment: @ikarus This 1D integral is calculated exactly in the article. Then you can easily draw the curves in Fig. 1. On the other hand, there is no numerical method for calculating `RF` from $10^{-50}$ to $10^{50}$. It is necessary to break the interval into several sub-intervals and use several different methods.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Do you mean by exactly, that they used Integrate instead of NIntegrate?

Comment: @ikarus Write down the integral in the general form, as you originally had it, to reproduce Fig. 1. We will simplify it and find the exact solution.

Comment: @AlexTrounev The upper form of RF[A] is already the general one. I haven't change its functional dependence. 
Using this form of RF[A] I do reproduce fig1. for mDM < mt. But even when RF[A] is error-free I get errors related to NIntegrate when I try to run NDSolve with this RF[A] inside it

Answer (score 2):

I can offer one working code. I checked this for a parameter set, but not sure if this works for any parameter sets

```
ma = 0; \[Alpha]S = 1; \[Alpha]V = 
 1/Log[10^5]; \[Alpha]H = 1; \[Alpha]G = 
 1/Log[10^5]; \[Beta]G = 0; \[Beta]V = 0; \[Alpha]\[Chi] = 1; \
\[Alpha]\[Chi]V = 1; \[Beta]\[Chi] = 0; \[Beta]\[Chi]5 = 0; g = 100; \
V = 10^5; Mpl = 2*10^18; \[Kappa]inf = 10^17; \[Kappa]b = 
 9*10^8; \[CapitalPhi]I = 4*10^43; \[CapitalGamma]infSM = 
 4*10^8; \[CapitalGamma]bSM = 7/10^11; minf = 6*10^14; mt = 
 2*10^10; TRHinf = 2*10^13; TRHb = 7*10^4; 
RF[(A_)?NumericQ, (mDM_)?NumericQ, (mt_)?NumericQ, (ma_)?
   NumericQ, (\[Alpha]H_)?NumericQ, (\[Alpha]G_)?
   NumericQ, (\[Alpha]\[Chi]_)?NumericQ, (\[Alpha]\[Chi]V_)?
   NumericQ, (\[Beta]\[Chi]_)?NumericQ, (\[Beta]\[Chi]5_)?
   NumericQ, (\[Beta]G_)?NumericQ, (\[Lambda]_)?
   NumericQ] := ((4*Pi)*
    NIntegrate[
     Norm[(Sqrt[
          1 - (4*mDM^2)/
            s]*(\[Alpha]\[Chi]^2*(mDM^2*
             s^3*(1 - (4*mDM^2)/s))*(4*\[Alpha]H^2 + 
              12*\[Alpha]G^2)^2)*\[Kappa]b*(A^(-3/2))^(1/4)*Sqrt[s]*
         BesselK[1, 
          Sqrt[s]/(\[Kappa]b*(A^(-3/2))^(1/4))])/(\[Lambda]^4*((s - 
              mt^2)^2 + 
           mt^2*((mt^3*((1/8)*\[Alpha]H^2*
                    Sqrt[1 - (4*89^2)/mt^2] + (3*\[Alpha]G^2)/
                    16))/(Pi*\[Lambda]^2) + (mt^3*
                  Sqrt[1 - (4*mDM^2)/mt^2]*\[Alpha]\[Chi]V^2*
                  mDM^2*(1 - (4*mDM^2)/mt^2))/((Pi*\[Lambda]^2)*8*
                  mt^2))^2))], {s, 4*mDM^2, Infinity}, 
     Exclusions -> {mt^2, ma^2}, AccuracyGoal -> 10])/(2048*Pi^6);
x[m_, l_] := 
 Module[{mDM = m, lambda = l}, 
  rf[A_] := 
   RF[A, mDM, mt, 
    ma, \[Alpha]H, \[Alpha]G, \[Alpha]\[Chi], \[Alpha]\[Chi]V, \
\[Beta]\[Chi], \[Beta]\[Chi]5, \[Beta]G, lambda];
  eq = {D[X[A], 
      A] == (A^(7/2)/TRHb^5)*((Sqrt[3]*Mpl*rf[A])/
        Sqrt[\[CapitalPhi][A] + 
          R[A]/A + (X[A]*
             Sqrt[mDM^2 + 9*\[Kappa]b^2*(A^(-3/2))^(1/2)])/TRHb]), 
    D[\[CapitalPhi][A], 
      A] == (-(A^(1/2)/TRHb^2))*((Sqrt[3]*Mpl*\[CapitalGamma]bSM)/
        Sqrt[\[CapitalPhi][A] + 
          R[A]/A + (X[A]*
             Sqrt[mDM^2 + 9*\[Kappa]b^2*(A^(-3/2))^(1/2)])/TRHb]), 
    D[R[A], A] == (\[CapitalGamma]bSM*\[CapitalPhi][
          A] - (1/TRHb^4)*(2*
           Sqrt[mDM^2 + 9*\[Kappa]b^2*(A^(-3/2))^(1/2)]*rf[A]*
           A^3))*((Sqrt[3]*Mpl*A^(3/2))/(TRHb^2*
          Sqrt[\[CapitalPhi][A] + 
            R[A]/A + (X[A]*
               Sqrt[mDM^2 + 9*\[Kappa]b^2*(A^(-3/2))^(1/2)])/TRHb]))};
  ic = {X[10^(-10)] == 0, \[CapitalPhi][10^(-10)] == \[CapitalPhi]I, 
    R[10^(-10)] == 0};
  f = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, X[A], {A, 10^(-10), 10^4}]; f]
    {Plot[Evaluate[x[10^8, 10^13]], {A, 10^(-10), 10^4}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"A", "X"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[x[10^8, 10^12]], {A, 10^(-10), 10^4}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"A", "X"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[x[10^9, 10^12]], {A, 10^(-10), 10^4}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"A", "X"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, it works indeed! But in order to reproduce Fig1. in the reference, I need to use Method -> "DoubleExponential" inside NIntegrate. Otherwise I do not get the right slope in the low A (or equivalently high T) regime of RF[A]. But when I use "DoubleExponential" I still get convergence/singularity errors. How can I get rid of those errros?

Comment: To reproduce Fig. 1, we must obtain an exact expression of the integral, or at least a piecewise function.`Plot` and `NDSolve` use `RF`  different ways.

Comment: Aah, I see. So you mean even though Plot[RF[A]] looks different then in Fig1. I can still trust it inside NDSolve?